# Select data from previous that have same id and I use 2 id, first id for param and second id for stop calculate

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have table name app_entity_240 and this table have many column, column c use for calculate from other column, and this table have 2 id parameters, when id2 is different then start from 0 not from previous row.

| id 2 | id 1 | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 200 |
| 2 | 4 | 200 |
| 2 | 5 | 300 |
| 2 | 6 | 400 |

```
select 
 @sum := case when @prev := id 
              then @sum + [3645] 
              else [3645] 
         end 
from app_entity_240
cross join
(select @sum := 0, @prev := 0) params
```

[3645] = data from other column

Below is what I expectation:

| id 2 | id 1 | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 200 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 200 |
| 2 | 6 | 300 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get cumulative sum of some column within same `id2` you can use query like this:

```sql
select *, sum(val) over (partition by id2 order by id1) columnC
  from my_table
```

*Here `val` is column containig values for aggregation.*

Every new block will begin with own value in `columnC`, and all consecutive rows within this block will add own value to previous value of `columnC`.

If you want blocks to start with 0, you can use

```sql
select *, sum(val) over (partition by id2 order by id1) - val columnnC
  from my_table
```

but value of last row in the block wouldn't be used in any of aggregation.

Demo of both queries can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/x5P4T0eo).